# React-Native Fast Refresh is not working version 0.70.3

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, fast-refresh

Reac- Native Fast Refresh is not working . I am using react-native version "0.70.3" . When I want to change any code in my project the page is not reloading . It should be automatic but it is not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should clean the cache first

```
npm start --cache-clean
```

> then run the app in mobile

```
npx react-native run-android / npx react-native run-ios
```

> shake your mobile a react-native Dev Menu will be popup
> then you can enable and disable the fast refresh